# Revel with Gorm "undefined: Page"

Tags: postgresql, go, orm, revel, go-gorm

I'm just trying to create new project with `revel`, `gorm` and `pq`.
I have model `Page` in `app/models`:

```
package models

import (
    "time"
)

type Page struct {
    Id        int64
    Title     string `sql:"size:255"`
    Context   string
    Url       string
    MetaKeys  string
    MetaDescr string
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt time.Time
}
```

and `gorm.go` in `app/controllers`:

```
package controllers

import (
    _ "myapp/app/models"
    _ "code.google.com/p/go.crypto/bcrypt"
    _ "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    _ "github.com/revel/revel"
    "github.com/revel/revel/modules/db/app"
)

var (
    DB gorm.DB
)

func InitDB() {
    db.Init()

    var err error
    DB, err = gorm.Open("postgres", "user=postgres dbname=mydb_development sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Got error when connect database, the error is '%v'", err))
    }

    DB.LogMode(true)

    DB.AutoMigrate(Page{})
}
```

I have the error `undefined: Page` in line `DB.AutoMigrate(Page{})`, but I linked my models in line `_ "myapp/app/models"`. What's wrong?

Comment: _ is a side effect import. "." imports the package into the current namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the package identifier of your model: as your model struct is defined in another package, it's name (locally to the `controllers` package) should be `models.Page`.

If you really want to get rid of the package identifier and do like it was locally defined, I think that you can also import your `models` package locally by assigning it to the `.` identifier. Example:

```
import (
    . "myapp/app/models"
)
```