# Revel: "code does not compile: undefined: models"

Tags: go, revel, gorp

I have created /app/models/todo-item.go file that looks like this:

```
package models

import (
  "github.com/revel/revel"
)

type TodoItem struct {
  Id              int64   `db:"id" json:"id"`
  Name            string  `db:"name" json:"name"`
}

func (b *TodoItem) Validate(v *revel.Validation) {

  v.Check(b.Name,
    revel.ValidRequired(),
    revel.ValidMaxSize(25))
}
```

In src/RevelApp/app/controllers/init.go, I have this (PS, I am using GorpController to interact with MySQL):

```
func defineTodoItemTable(dbm *gorp.DbMap){
  // set "id" as primary key and autoincrement
  t := dbm.AddTable(models.TodoItem{}).SetKeys(true, "id") 
  t.ColMap("name").SetMaxSize(25)
}
```

I am getting an error :
**The Go code src/RevelApp/app/controllers/init.go does not compile: undefined: models**

I have tried importing ."RevelApp/app/models" then doing away with models in models.TodoItem{} (as describer here: [Revel with Gorm "undefined: Page"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409631/revel-with-gorm-undefined-page)) and I get the error : **App failed to start up
revel/harness: app timed out**.

That link is the only one I could find related to this issue. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**: $GOPATH:

```
/home/me/Source/go
```

models location:

```
/home/me/Source/go/src/RevelApp/app/models
```

How I am importing models package:

```
import (
    ."RevelApp/app/models"
    "github.com/revel/revel"
    "github.com/coopernurse/gorp"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)
```

Comment: This could be `GOPATH` related - can you show us how you're importing the `models` package and where its located relative to your `GOPATH`?

Comment: I have edited the question with what you have asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported your models using the dot (`.`) import qualifier. From the language spec:

> If an explicit period (.) appears instead of a name, all the package's exported identifiers will be declared in the current file's file block and can be accessed without a qualifier.

This means you don't need to use `models.TodoItem` .. you can simply use `TodoItem`.

That said .. I would suggest avoiding this and removing the dot from the import statement:

```
import (
    "RevelApp/app/models"
    "github.com/revel/revel"
    "github.com/coopernurse/gorp"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)
```

Why? It stops your local file scope becoming crowded and allows you to see where each object actually resides.

For completeness (and you're probably wondering what its for since the dot is similar), that underscore (`_`) before the `mysql` package statement basically says "import this package .. but I don't need to use anything in it directly". This fires the packages `init` function allowing it to register itself with the `database/sql` packages routines. Which is why when you use the `sql.DB` type it is eventually routed to the MySql package code.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this answer. Unfortunately, your suggestion is the first way I did it and still got the error of 'imported and not used: "RevelApp/app/models" '. 

I only used the (.) because the only other problem I could find in Google suggested that solution in the provided answer.

Comment: @Mardwan then remove the `.` from your sample code. If you do that, it should work. If you still have an error, then we need more details to find out what the real issue is.